# Trying to upgrade React Native from 59.10 to latest version

Tags: react-native, upgrade

Trying to upgrade React Native from 59.10 to latest version , i made a new project and move the old ones and change the one who has conflict with React/Core but now i am getting a problem for ListView which is not used in codes ,

> Invariant Violation: ListView has been removed from React Native.

here is my package.json and the error , i also see a blank page in emulator with no error .

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I check your packages included.

Finally, I check out `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`.
With some search in v0.7.4, I found [this](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/blob/aad61a8487ceeb7c4bb0bf552c009b5a901da356/lib/KeyboardAwareListView.js#L3) line that raises an error for you.
But how can you solve that?

- Just update this package to the latest version. The problem is
  solved by this [PR](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/pull/327).

Comment: it  was not related to that, i upgrade to the latest version and nothing happen , the same error